# Unable to scrape async script with cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am using cheerio to make a crawler but in some websites, scripts are asyncronous, and when I try to get all the scripts from it, they are not picked.
Here is the code I use :

```
function Test(webUrl) {
    request(webUrl, function(err, resp, html){
        if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            console.log($('script'));
        }
    });
}
```

Is someone having any solution ? Thanks

Comment: Cheerio does not load or run embedded `<script>` tags that it finds in the content.  So, you get the RAW HTML only, not any content insert from scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use PhantomJS for scraping dynamic content.

Here is example: http://code4node.com/snippet/web-scraping-with-node-and-phantomjs

Comment: Mmmmh tried to do it with the tutorial you gave me but the example is not working, and I can't figure out how to apply it to my program ...